# How to display a visitor's IP address by ipware app?

Tags: django, ip

I want to get the user's IP address when he visits my site, I found many solutions but I picked one of them which is: ipware application that I installed it but when I used it the result returned: 127.0.0.1 which is localhost not the IP of my device

my experience using IP is weak but I understand a little bit why it returned that result I think that because I'm on the localhost so, it uses a private IP as I thought so if that answer is correct How could I try to print the user's IP of the anonymous user before I upload the website on production to show the expected result and sure that everything's ok now?

```
from ipware import get_client_ip

print(get_client_ip(request))
```

Comment: Access your server through something other than `localhost`… E.g., find out your LAN address and access it via that.

Comment: could u please explain more, which server may I use like what?